# How to compare different clusters of different size, rotation, scale and translation?

Tags: clustering, optimization, linear-algebra, svd, procrustes-analysis

Assume that you have a matrix $X$ that contains the data inside the left image. The data inside $X$ is not classified. The matrix $X$ also contains outliers/noise.

On the right, we can se the template data matrix $Y$, that shows almost the same size as the data inside $X$, without the outliers/noise, except that the data in $X$ is shaped like a $K$ and the template data is shaped like an $H$.

The data in $X$ is in different scale, translation and rotation compared to the data in $Y$.

**Question:**

I know that there is a method called Procrustes Analysis that will transform unknow data and fit it to a template and measure euclidean distance between the closest neighbour. But the problem with Procrustes Analysis is that it requries the same amout of size of data, as the template that being used. Procrustes Analysis is only invariant to:

- Rotation
- Scale
- Translation

I'm looking for an algorithm that can give me and approximation how well an unknow data will fit a template with different:

- Rotation
- Scale
- Translation
- Size

I want to get the best fit and then compare the fit and the outliers should not affect the fit. What can be used to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: How do you define or characterize "outliers" for this purpose?  It sounds like you have two very nearly separate problems: (1) identify outliers and (2) match all *remaining* data up to an element of the affine group of the plane.  Is there a reason to be considering these problems simultaneously?

Comment: @whuber Well, I don't know outliers if I only plot $X$. But if I compare $X$ with $Y$ at the correct size, rotation and translation. Then I can see the outliers - visually and computationally.  No, there is no reason to consider these problems simultaneously. Once one problem (2 - matching) is done, then outliers will be no concern.

Comment: @whuber Can `RANSAC` be used in this case?

Comment: Possibly it can be used to identify outliers, assuming you can propose a successful model for the inliers.  That does not seem to be the case in your example.